# What does "sup" mean in the context of a w type?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, induction

Like the constructor for a W type is called "sup" but I don't know what that expands to. Is it super? maybe supremum? Or is it just an arbitrary name, like dynamic programming?

Comment: For an authoritative reference see pg 43 of [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelt/martin-lof/master/pdfs/Bibliopolis-Book-retypeset-1984.pdf) retyped version of Martin-Löf's "Intuitionistic type theory", where at the bottom it says "Think of sup(a, b) as the supremum ...".

Comment: A quote from a book: [The constructor sup (short for supremum)](https://books.google.be/books?id=LkDUKMv3yp0C&pg=PA155)